# Complexity of the coset intersection problem

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, graph-isomorphism, gr.group-theory

Given the symmetry group $S_n$ and two subgroups $G, H\leq S_n$, and $\pi\in S_n$, does $G\pi\cap H=\emptyset$ hold?

As far as I know, the problem is known as the coset intersection problem. I am wondering what's the complexity? In particular, is this problem known to be in coAM?

Moreover, if $H$ is restricted to be abelian, what does the complexity become?

Comment: How are the two groups represented as input?

Comment: by convention, they are given by sets of generators.

Comment: The coset intersection problem is typically phrased oppositely: the answer is yes iff they intersect. It is this version of the problem that's in $\mathsf{NP} \cap \mathsf{coAM}$.

Comment: An interesting side note, which invalidates none of the above: graph isomorphism, coset intersection, and string isomorphism were all the subject of a new result by Babai first described in a seminar a couple of days ago. No publication yet, but it looks like there is now a quasi-polynomial algorithm for all of them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Moderately exponential time and $\mathsf{coAM}$ (for the opposite of the problem as stated: Coset Intersection is typically considered to have a "yes" answer if the cosets intersect, opposite of how it's stated in the OQ.)

[Luks 1999](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/301250.301427) ([free author's copy](http://ix.cs.uoregon.edu/~luks/StocHyper.pdf)) gave a $2^{O(n)}$-time algorithm, while Babai (see his 1983 Ph.D. thesis, also [Babai-Kantor-Luks FOCS 1983](http://doi.ieeecomputersociety.org/10.1109/SFCS.1983.10), and a to-appear journal version) gave a $2^{\tilde{O}(\sqrt{n})}$-time algorithm, which remains the best known to date. Since graph isomorphism reduces to quadratic-sized coset intersection, improving this to $2^{\tilde{O}(n^{1/4-\epsilon})}$ would improve the state of the art for graph isomorphism.

Answer (score 9):

Consider the complement, i.e. where you are asked to test whether $G \pi \cap H \not= \emptyset$. As I pointed out in [this answer](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/25827/complexity-of-permutation-related-problems/25835#25835), testing whether $g \in \langle g_1, \ldots, g_k\rangle$ is in $\text{NC} \subseteq \text{P}$ [1]. So you can guess $g, h \in S_n$ and test in polynomial time whether $g \in G$, $h \in H$ and $g \pi = h$. This yields an $\text{NP}$ upper bound and, therefore, your problem is in $\text{coNP}$.

**Edit**: It is shown in [2, Thm. 15] that the coset intersection problem is in $\text{NP} \cap \text{coAM}$. As noted [here](http://www.mathunion.org/ICM/ICM1990.2/Main/icm1990.2.1479.1490.ocr.pdf), p. 7, the coset intersection problem is therefore not NP-complete, unless the polynomial time hierarchy collapses. Moreover, it is noted [here](http://www.mathunion.org/ICM/ICM1990.2/Main/icm1990.2.1479.1490.ocr.pdf), p. 6, that it was shown by Luks that the problem is in $\text{P}$ when $H$ is solvable, which include the case of $H$ abelian.

[1] [L. Babai, E. M. Luks & A. Seress. *Permutation groups in NC*. Proc. 19th annual ACM symposium on Theory of computing, pp. 409-420, 1987.](http://ix.cs.uoregon.edu/~luks/NC.pdf)

[2]  [L. Babai, S. Moran. *Arthur-Merlin games: A randomized proof system, and a hierarchy of complexity classes*. Journal of Computer and System Sciences, vol. 36, issue 2, pp. 254-276, 1988.](http://crypto.cs.mcgill.ca/~crepeau/COMP647/2007/TOPIC01/AMgames-Babai-Moran.pdf)

Comment: many thanks for the answer. For the case H is a normal subgroup, it is clear. However, if H is just abelian, it is not really clear for me. Does $GH=<{st: s\in S, t\in T}>$ still hold? (sorry for my stupidity...)

Comment: My bad, my brain mixed "normal" and "solvable" for a moment. I'm sorry. I edited the answer, I hope it answers your question.

Comment: When H is a normal subgroup of G, the coset intersection problem is much easier: it reduces to just the membership problem (is $\pi$ in G).

Comment: Right, thank you. That part of my answer is pretty much worthless then.

Comment: I removed the paragraph, it was just confusing.